# Make multiple scaffold with single Tabs bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation, flutter-scaffold, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am building a flutter app where the user requirement is to build 3 tabs with each tab having custom AppBar which implies to have multiple Scaffolds in each view.

So I have main.dart, screen.dart, account.dart and post.dart

3 tabs => Screen, Account and Post 
Screen View => Appbar with just name 
Account View => Appbar with Hamburger Icon 
Post View => Appbar with Plus icon

According to flutter we can have Appbar and Bottom Navigation Bar (Tabs Bar) inside Scaffold Widget. So to have multiple Scaffolds, I would have to make 3 seperate bottom navigation bar or is there any other way to achieve this functionality?

Also, if we need to make 3 different Bottom Navigation Bar per Scaffold, then how to navigate between them since my first view will be called from main.dart

Thanks for helping and taking out your time to answer the question.